# npm install puppeteer in docker not working when volume is mounted on windows

Tags: docker, puppeteer

I have a tool that as part of running, is doing npm install puppeteer.

```
docker run --rm mytool
```

Above works, and its puppeteer is installed under /tmphost/node_modules/puppeteer as expected by the tool.

I am on windows running docker. and if i now for caching perposes want to not install it everytime my tool should run, want to mount a volumn for the /tmphost path. It fails to install puppeteer.

```
docker run --rm -v c:/data/tmphostcache:/tmphost mytool
```

It fails with

```
fs.js:120
    throw err;
Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, open '/tmphost/node_modules/puppteer/package.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:449:3)
```

Any suggestions to what to try do to find out why it cant install it when the folder is mounted.

Other npm modules works fine.

Comment: Have you been able to get this working in the end?